# Apache cannot find correct version of libmysqlclient

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, cgi

I'm trying to write a cgi form handler using cgicc and mysql++. Everything is installed on my machine, and the C++ compiles and links fine into the .cgi file, but when I try to test in on apache, I get a 500 Internal Server error.

This is the line from error.log

```
[Sun Sep 25 10:29:53.759858 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 6186] [client 127.0.0.1:47526] AH01215: /var/www/html/getUsers.cgi: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory: /var/www/html/getUsers.cgi, referer: http://localhost/form.html
```

Apache is looking for libmysqlclient.so.18, but I think I have.20 installed. That said, libmysqlclient.so.18 does exist on my machine, found it with `find /usr | grep libmysqlclient`.

How do I either:

1. Tell apache to look for libmysqlclient.so.20 instead, or,
2. Tell apache where it can actually find .so.18?

Versions:

- Apache 2.4.18
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15
- Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Thanks, I'll try there instead